# Renaming columns after merging data in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, rename

I have two Pandas series which I merged using the following code:

```
HS4_Tariffs_16=pd.concat([df_tariff_HS4_16_PT,df_tariff_HS4_16_MFN],axis=1)
```

If you are wondering why I used concat in place of merge, the error 'Series' object has no attribute 'merge' showed up when I used merge.
So anyway, I merged the two series using concat which resulted in a dataframe. Thereafter, I reset the index using the code:

```
HS4_Tariffs_16.reset_index()
```

Now the real problem cropped up when I tried to rename a column using the code:

```
HS4_Tariffs_16=HS4_Tariffs_16.rename(columns={'ProductCode':'HSCode'})
```

Instead of renaming the column, it converted the column to an index. The output was someting like this:

```
      Preferential tariff for APTA countries    MFN duties (Applied)
ProductCode         
101     0.3     0.3
102     0.3     0.3
103     0.3     0.3
104     0.3     0.3
105     0.3     0.3
...     ...     ...
9702    0.1     0.1
9703    0.1     0.1
9704    0.0     0.0
9705    0.1     0.1
9706    0.1     0.1

1224 rows × 2 columns
```

Could you tell me which part of the code I need to correct if the final result that I want is a dataframe with the column named 'ProductCode' renamed as 'HSCode'.

Comment: What does the df look like before you attempt to rename? I don't think the error is in your renaming

Comment: You never *actually* reset the index. change `HS4_Tariffs_16` to: `HS4_Tariffs_16 = HS4_Tariffs_16.reset_index()` Then run your `rename` and see if you get the result you expect.

Comment: Thanks a lot @CameronRiddell. It worked!

Comment: I'm voting to close this as caused by a typo / not reproducible

Answer (score 1):

The following might work without having to reset the index. It could be setting it as index as you're renaming the frame as itself when you rename the column and Pandas is weird like that sometimes!

```
HS4_Tariffs_16.rename(columns={'ProductCode':'HSCode'}, inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `rename_axis` method to change the name of index columns. This avoids changing the data and adding a potentially unnecessary new index column.

```py
HS4_Tariffs_16.rename_axis(index={'ProductCode':'HSCode'}, inplace=True)
```

You can also do this in one step using round brackets for cleaner code:

```py
HS4_Tariffs_16 = (
    pd.concat([df_tariff_HS4_16_PT, df_tariff_HS4_16_MFN], axis=1)
    .rename_axis(index={'ProductCode':'HSCode'})
)
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
df=df.rename({'Old_name' : 'New_name'}, axis=1)

In your case 

HS4_Tariffs_16= HS4_Tariffs_16.rename({'ProductCode':'HSCode'}, axis=1)
```

Or you can create a copy with the name you want and remove original then:

```
df['renamed']=df['oldname'].copy()
df= df.drop('oldname', axis=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try these two possible solutions:

```
HS4_Tariffs_16 = HS4_Tariffs_16.reset_index().rename(columns={"ProductCode": "HSCode"})
```

or

```
HS4_Tariffs_16.reset_index(inplace=True) 
HS4_Tariffs_16.rename(columns={"ProductCode": "HSCode"}, inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is arising when you reset the index. Try this:

```
HS4_Tariffs_16.reset_index(drop = True)
```

Answer (score 1):

The simple workaround is: use the array of values from your resultant and create a new dataframe out of it and pass new column names of your choice the code snippet might look like this.

```
    HS4_Tariffs_16=pd.concat([df_tariff_HS4_16_PT,df_tariff_HS4_16_MFN],axis=1)
    HS4_Tariffs_16=pd.DataFrame(HS4_Tariffs_16.values, columns=["new_col_name1", "new_col_name_2"])
```

Answer (score 1):

**The main problem is that you did not use the result of `HS4_Tariffs_16.reset_index()`**. You can solve this by using it like this:

```
HS4_Tariffs_16 = HS4_Tariffs_16.reset_index()
```

or you can simply set inplace parameter to apply reset_index on HS4_Tariffs_16. like this:

```
HS4_Tariffs_16.reset_index(inplace= True)
```

But **why did this happen**? based on [pandas documentations](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/getting_started/overview.html#data-structures), dataFrame (df) is **mutable structure**, so every function that takes it as an argument, and change it, this will change original df. So, in this function, programmers usually **create a copy of df and change it to preserve the original df**. So, using functions such as `reset_index()`, `sort_values()`, `rename()`, and ... will not modify original df. However, you can use inplace=True or use the returned df.